# JSF @SessionScoped Managed Bean – WebLogic cluster replication

Tags: jsf, weblogic, cluster-computing

Technology stack:

```
      WebLogic 12.1.3

      JSF 2.1

      Primefaces 6.1
```

I am seeking advice on how to code a @SessionScoped ManagedBean to replicate across all the servers clustered.

My assumption is that once SessionScoped an object should replicate on all clustered servers, with all the properties at current value.

While moving to a clustered WebLogic platform, I was testing to see if the current JSF applications would carry the Session values across all the servers in the cluster. My test turned out as fail. Then I’ve tried writing a simple application to monitor how are the ViewScoped and the SessionScoped objects behave.
The WebLogic cluster is configured like this

[image: img0]

ManagedServer_1 has an IP x.x.x.212 and listens to port 7003
ManagedServer_2 has an IP x.x.x.212 and listens to port 7004
I use Fiddler to enable port resolution

I’m using a simple, one page JSP Web Application, where I update a value on the back model.
The web application
Weblogic.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
      <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <debug>true</debug>
      </jsp-descriptor>
      <context-root>/SessionTest</context-root>
      <session-descriptor> 
        <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
        <debug-enabled>true</debug-enabled> 
      </session-descriptor>
    </weblogic-web-app>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
            <param-value>Development</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <distributable/>
    </web-app>
```

Index.xhtml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
     <title>Session Replication Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
     <h:form>
        <p:growl id="grw" widgetVar="grw" showDetail="true"/>            
        <p:panel id="panel1" header="Ajax Panel @ ${controller.model.serverIP}:${controller.model.serverPort}">
            <p:inputText id="name_input" value="${model.name}" widgetVar="name_in">
                <p:ajax update="@this"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <br/><br/>
            <p:commandButton id="name_command" value="Call Ajax" actionListener="${controller.updateNameLabel(model.name)}" update="@form"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <p:outputLabel id="name_output" value="Hello ${model.name} * ${model.clicks}"/>
        </p:panel>            
      </h:form>
     </h:body>
    </html>
```

Backing index.xhtml, we have a

Model class

```
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class Model implements Serializable {

        private String name;
        private int clicks;
        private String serverIP;
        private String serverPort;
    public Model() {
            name = "";
            clicks = 0;
            serverIP = "";
            serverPort = "";
            System.out.println("---------- Model constructor -----------");
    }

      // Emmanuel's suggestion applied here
      private void pushSesssion(){
          HttpSession httpSession = fetchSession();
          httpSession.setAttribute("model", this);
      }

      private HttpSession fetchSession(){
         ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
         HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(false);
         return httpSession;
       }

      … getters and setters

       public void setClicks(int clicks) {
         this.clicks = clicks;
         pushSesssion();
       }
       // Emmanuel's suggestion - End

    }
```

.. and a

Controller class

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class Controller implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{model}")
    private Model model;

    /**
    * Creates a new instance of Actions
    */
    public Controller() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    System.out.println("----------------- Controller initializing @ " + new Date()+" ------------------------");
    fetchIP();
    }

    private void fetchIP() {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest(); 
    String localIP = request.getLocalAddr();
    int localPort = request.getLocalPort();
    if(!model.getServerIP().equals(localIP) || !model.getServerPort().equals(localPort+"")){
        addFacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Server Changed","Please wait 30 seconds before next click.");
        model.setServerIP(localIP);
        model.setServerPort(localPort+"");        
    }
    }

    private HttpSession fetchSession(){
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(false);
    return httpSession;
    }

    public void updateNameLabel(String name) {
    HttpSession httpSession = fetchSession();
    System.out.println("DBG  - "+new Date()+" HttpSession  -- " + httpSession.getId());

    System.out.println("---------------------- DBG 1 -------------------");        
    System.out.println("DBG 1 - model is still local  -- ");
    System.out.println("DBG 1 - HttpSession.model.clicks = " + ((Model)httpSession.getAttribute("model")).getClicks());
    System.out.println("DBG 1 - this.model.clicks = " + model.getClicks());

    model = (Model)httpSession.getAttribute("model");        
    fetchIP();                
    model.setName(name);
    model.setClicks(model.getClicks() + 1);

    System.out.println("---------------------- DBG 2 -------------------");
    System.out.println("DBG 2 - model loaded from httpSession  -- ");        
    System.out.println("DBG 2 - HttpSession.model.clicks = " + ((Model)httpSession.getAttribute("model")).getClicks());
    System.out.println("DBG 2 - this.model.clicks = " + model.getClicks());

    }
```

In the controller I print the value of click from the HTTPSession attribute object and current object, to make sure it is the same.

Running the application:

I use Fiddler to enable port resolution, as I run the cluster on my development PC, hence only one IP is available
At the top I list the IP of the server we hit (x.x.x.212:7003).

[image: img1]

For every click, the counter after Hello XXXX * increases.

Now, if I switch to port 7004 and I’m expecting the next counter to be 4, but it goes back to 0

[image]

Here is the output from the servers

**:7003**

```
    ---------- Model constructor -----------
    ----------------- Controller initializing @ Wed Apr 04 09:05:46 EDT 2018 -------
    DBG  - Wed Apr 04 09:05:56 EDT 2018 HttpSession  -- **k6yQw2Hd_EKgK7OanKloEHbCKkEMpv9TQfxrXd-8tj05fNlnH8O-!-1996882782!-1285789144!1522847146467**
    ---------------------- DBG 1 -------------------
    DBG 1 - model is still local  -- 
    DBG 1 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 0
    DBG 1 - this.model.clicks = 0
    ---------------------- DBG 2 -------------------
    DBG 2 - model loaded from httpSession  -- 
    DBG 2 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 1
    DBG 2 - this.model.clicks = 1

    DBG  - Wed Apr 04 09:05:57 EDT 2018 HttpSession  -- k6yQw2Hd_EKgK7OanKloEHbCKkEMpv9TQfxrXd-8tj05fNlnH8O-!-1996882782!-1285789144!1522847146467

    ---------------------- DBG 1 -------------------
    DBG 1 - model is still local  -- 
    DBG 1 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 1
    DBG 1 - this.model.clicks = 1
    ---------------------- DBG 2 -------------------
    DBG 2 - model loaded from httpSession  -- 
    DBG 2 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 2
    DBG 2 - this.model.clicks = 2
```

**...**

```
    DBG  - Wed Apr 04 09:05:59 EDT 2018 HttpSession  -- k6yQw2Hd_EKgK7OanKloEHbCKkEMpv9TQfxrXd-8tj05fNlnH8O-!-1996882782!-1285789144!1522847146467
    ---------------------- DBG 1 -------------------
    DBG 1 - model is still local  -- 
    DBG 1 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 7
    DBG 1 - this.model.clicks = 7
    ---------------------- DBG 2 -------------------
    DBG 2 - model loaded from httpSession  -- 
    DBG 2 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 8
    DBG 2 - this.model.clicks = 8
```

**:7004**

```
    DBG  - Wed Apr 04 09:06:12 EDT 2018 HttpSession  --k6yQw2Hd_EKgK7OanKloEHbCKkEMpv9TQfxrXd-8tj05fNlnH8O-!-1285789144!-1996882782!1522847146467
    ---------------------- DBG 1 -------------------
    DBG 1 - model is still local  -- 
    DBG 1 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 0
    DBG 1 - this.model.clicks = 0
    ---------------------- DBG 2 -------------------
    DBG 2 - model loaded from httpSession  -- 
    DBG 2 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 1
    DBG 2 - this.model.clicks = 1
```

**...**

```
    DBG  - Wed Apr 04 09:06:17 EDT 2018 HttpSession  --k6yQw2Hd_EKgK7OanKloEHbCKkEMpv9TQfxrXd-8tj05fNlnH8O-!-1285789144!-1996882782!1522847146467
    ---------------------- DBG 1 -------------------

    DBG 1 - model is still local  -- 
    DBG 1 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 11
    DBG 1 - this.model.clicks = 11
    ---------------------- DBG 2 -------------------
    DBG 2 - model loaded from httpSession  -- 
    DBG 2 - HttpSession.model.clicks = 12
    DBG 2 - this.model.clicks = 12
```

Looking at the session ID, it seems to be the same session

On 7003

**k6yQw2Hd_EKgK7OanKloEHbCKkEMpv9TQfxrXd-8tj05fNlnH8O-!-1996882782!-1285789144!1522847146467**

On 7004

**k6yQw2Hd_EKgK7OanKloEHbCKkEMpv9TQfxrXd-8tj05fNlnH8O-!-1285789144!-1996882782!1522847146467**

, with the JVM Hash mirrored

**-1996882782!-1285789144** on port 7003

**-1285789144!-1996882782** on port 7004

Still, the Model object is not carried on, or it is reinitialized when the port changes.

If you have time to read this, I thank you for your patience and eventual help.

This is the reply from Oracle support:

Goal:

Session object attribute changes do not seem to replicate across the cluster.

Solution:

When there is a change in the session object attribute, always use setAttribute, then the object and its attributes are replicated in a cluster using in-memory replication.

Likewise, use removeAttribute to remove an attribute from a session object.

Comment: Does session replication work at all? E.g. use a plain jsp with a value that is put in the session? JSF has know knowledge of these backing things.

Comment: Cluster replication (in memory) is used for failover. In normal circumstances each client is sticked to a single JVM via the JSESSIONID.
Also, don't forget that the replication process is fired each time the Session.setAttribute() method is called. If you just update your objects without calling setAttribute, the replication will not occur.

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel. I was testing the failover, stopping one of the servers hoping the live one will pick up and carry on. But it wasn't working. That's why I made this little app to test.  Anyway, if I have to .setAttribute for every property change, it means that I cannot simply port a previously written app, I'll may have to adjust all the setters to set the class attribute.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel. Just want to confirm that your suggestion worked. Still seems odd to me that the Session replicates but not its attributes. I wonder if there is a way to do this through a set-up rather than programmatically push the SessionScoped object into an attribute.

Comment: Thank you Bauke for your reply. Oracle states that "the distributable element is not used by WebLogic Server". I gave it a try anyway, but it does not solve my problem (I've added the web.xml in the question body). I still have to push the session attribute. I'll inquire with Oracle next, maybe there is another setting. I thought my problem it's due to a simple/obvious oversight, that's why I did not go to Oracle yet. Could still be ...

Comment: After inquiring with Oracle support, I will accept Emmanuel's answer as the correct solution. Thank you.